# SimpleDateFormat without the Timezone Offset in Java (GMT+00:00) for Custom Timezone

Tags: java, timezone, simpledateformat

Is it possible to format a date time in Java using the SimpleDateFormat class to give the timezone part of a date without having the +0000 after it.

**Edit**

We are changing the Default Timezone within Java as follows:

```
SimpleTimeZone tz = new SimpleTimeZone(0, "Out Timezone");        
TimeZone.setDefault(tz);
```

Unfortunately, I am in no position to remove this code.  I would hazard a guess at the whole system stopping working.  I think the initial author put this in to work around some day light saving issues.

With this in mind, I want to format the date as:

**2011-12-27 09:00 GMT**

or

**2011-12-27 09:00 BST**

I can only get the SimpleDateFormat to output as:

2011-12-27 09:00:00 GMT+00:00

which uses the format string **yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z**

I cannot see anywhere where the simple timezone has any reference to winter time (GMT) id or summer time id (BST).

Comment: `System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z").format(new Date()));` for me just returns `2011-11-22 13:42:16 GMT`. Does that line display the offset for you as well?

Comment: @berry120 - yes that works.  It could be an issue with the JIDE components I am using the SimpleDateFormat for then by the looks of it.  Will investigate a bit more.  Put this on as an answer and I will accept it.  Thanks Andez.

Comment: It prints GMT+offset for me as well, on both JDK 1.7.0 and 1.6.0_23 in Eclipse Indigo SR1 on Windows 7 x64. I'm not sure why others don't get +offset and how to get rid of it.

Comment: @BalusC I think it happens if the JDK doesn't know the name of your timezone - in which case it defaults to displaying GMT offset.

Comment: @sudo: Ah that makes sense. I'm at BOT (GMT-4). Berry indeed lives in UK (which is GMT already) and you probably also?

Comment: All...  The problem is in our code which changes the default timezone, to a custom timezone.  I have updated the question.

Comment: I am able to execute this code with the desired output on my local machine. However, we are unable to successfully build the code in Jenkins because of the Timezone code. Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not an elegant solution at all but it works for us.  I had to create a custom implementation for DateFormat/SimpleDateFormat.  This looks like something as follows:

```
static {
    // this would be initialized like something as follows when the application starts
    // which causes the headaches of SimpleDateFormat not to work...
    SimpleTimeZone tz = new SimpleTimeZone(0, "Out Timezone");             
    TimeZone.setDefault(tz);  
}

// therefore this class will workaround the issue, 

public class OurOwnCustomDateFormat
    extends SimpleDateFormat {

    /** The pattern to use as the format string. */
    protected String pattern;

    public OurOwnCustomDateFormat(String pattern) {
         super(pattern);
         // store the pattern
         this.pattern = pattern;
    }

    @Override
    public StringBuffer format(Date date, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos) {

         // custom implementation to format the date and time based on our TimeZone            
         toAppendTo.insert(pos.getBeginIndex(), "the date with our custom format calculated here");
         return toAppendTo; 
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

This Question and the Answers are now outmoded. They use old date-time classes outmoded by the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later. The old classes are poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome; **Avoid them**.

## Avoid 3-4 Letter Zone Codes

Avoid the 3-4 letter codes such as `BST`. They are neither standardized nor unique. They do not actually represent time zones. And they add even more confusion to the problem of Daylight Saving Time (DST).

Instead, use [proper time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Most are `continent/region` format such as [`Europe/London`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/London).

## Avoid setting default time zone

Calling [`java.util.TimeZone.setDefault`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault-java.util.TimeZone-) should be done only in the most extreme cases. This call affects all code running in all threads of all apps within the JVM immediately *during* runtime.

Instead, in all your date-time code, specify the desired/expected time zone. If omitted, Java falls back by implicitly relying on the JVM’s current default time zone. As noted above this default can change at any moment during runtime! Instead, specify explicitly. If you specify your desired/expected time zone as a passed argument routinely then the current default time zone is moot, irrelevant.

## java.time

The java.time framework is built into Java 8 and later. See [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Defined by JSR 310. Inspired by the highly successful Joda-Time library.

### `Instant`

An `Instant` is a moment on the timeline in UTC.

The following example shows how the java.time classes can parse/generate strings by default if in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, with no need to specify a parsing pattern. Use `DateTimeFormatter` class to specify other non-standard patterns.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2011-12-27T09:00:00Z" );
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

Apply a time zone as needed, producing a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( zoneId );
```

### Generating Strings

You can produce textual representations of the ZonedDateTime object using a `DateTimeFormatter`. You can specify custom patterns. Or, as I recommend, let java.time localize for you.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.MEDIUM );
```

Best to specify the desired/expected [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) for the same reason as time zone… the JVM’s current default can be changed at any moment by any code in any thread of any app running within the JVM. The `Locale` determines (a) the human language used for names of day & month, and (b) the cultural norms such as commas versus periods and the order of the parts such as month or day or year coming first.

```
formatter = formatter.withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );
String output = zdt.format( formatter );
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

I think that you are using the correct pattern for your requirements, however the JDK doesn't know the name of your timezone, so it switches over to using a [GMT offset value](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone) instead.

When I format a date using your pattern, I get "GMT" for the timezone part.

What does `TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName()` give you? For me, I get "Greenwich Mean Time".

Comment: Thanks sudocode...  It helped identify the problem as there is some nasty code in there to set the default timezone to a custom timezone.

Comment: I lived in Taipei, I called `TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName()` at my Android phone, it gives me `Taipei Standard Time`

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot reproduce this problem on my computer. I guess this would relate about localization. Try this

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z",Locale.US).format(new Date()));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Localisation - yep, it looks like it.  I have updated the question with some more information since you all mentioned it.

Comment: I think you really have to change "out timezone" to something correct like "America/Los_Angeles". If you want to avoid daylight saving, the new SimpleTimeZone(0, "America/Los_Angeles") constructor already void that. Read its api doc.

Comment: Thanks Surasin.  Will check it out

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z").format(new Date()));` for me just returns `2011-11-22 13:42:16 GMT` - so appears to work as you wish. Looks like it might be a problem elsewhere, you shouldn't need to create your own formatter class though.

Comment: Yes.  The finger of blame is now pointed back at us (not me).  There is part of the system which calls a TimeZone.setDefault(new SimpleTimeZone(0, "our own name").  I have inherited this and I am not too sure what the way forward is.  :-( Andez

Comment: @Andez The solution is to never rely on the default time zone. Always use the java.time classes rather than the troublesome legacy classes (`Date`/`Calendar`), and always pass the optional `ZoneId` argument to specify your expected/desired zone.